# Truth Tables and Implications Query

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$$
\begin{array}{ | m{5em} | m{1cm}| m{1cm} | } 
\hline
p& q & r & (p\vee \neg q)\to r \\ 
\hline
F & F & F & F \\ 
\hline
F & F & T & T \\ 
\hline
F & T & F & T \\
\hline
F & T & T & T \\
\hline
T & F & F & F \\
\hline
T & F & T & T \\
\hline
T & T & F & F \\
\hline
T & T & T & T \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
I am having some difficulty understanding this truth table. What I don't understand is that, how can  $F~~T~~F$ be true, yet $F~~F~~F$ is false?

Any explanations will be appreciated :)

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

If $p$, $q$ and $r$ are all false, $p\vee \neg q = F \vee T$ is true. But $T \to F$ is false, so the total expression is false.

If instead $q$ is true, $p\vee \neg q = F \vee F$ is false. Because $F \to F$ is true, the total expression is true.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, sorry, what do you mean by F v T?

Comment: False 'or' True

Comment: Sorry I got my head around that, writing it that way was just unfamiliar to me. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

**Case FTF -**

$p\vee \neg q$

$F \vee F = F$

Now,

$(p\vee \neg q)\to r$

$F \to F = T$

As false can implies false.

**Case FFF -**

$p\vee \neg q$

$F \vee T = T$

Now,

$(p\vee \neg q)\to r$

$T \to F = F$

As true cannot implies false.

Comment: wjkk wjkf, thank you for the reply

Comment: See this one. If any doubt please ask.

Comment: Mine pleasure bro :-)